# log4j2 JDBC Appender Issue:Failed to Insert Record

Tags: java, logging, jdbc, log4j, log4j2

I have created a JDBC appender and bind the ColumnConfig and DataSourceConnectionSource .

while trying to insert record in the DB (Logger.debug("Test")).I am getting below exception.

Thanks

```
[6/16/14 18:44:58:647 GMT-08:00] 00000024 SystemErr     R ERROR StatusLogger An exception occurred processing Appender JDBCAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Failed to insert record for log event in JDBC manager: DSRA1300E: Feature is not implemented: PreparedStatement.setNString
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JDBCDatabaseManager.writeInternal(JDBCDatabaseManager.java:117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:97)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger$PrivateConfig.logEvent(Logger.java:275)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.actualAsyncLog(AsyncLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.execute(RingBufferLogEvent.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:28)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: DSRA1300E: Feature is not implemented: PreparedStatement.setNString
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.notSupportedX(AdapterUtil.java:1306)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.setNString(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JDBCDatabaseManager.writeInternal(JDBCDatabaseManager.java:104)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java/sql/PreparedStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.setNString(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:2346)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My previous answer was incorrect, apologies.
It is possible to modify this behaviour [by configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender). By default, all columns (except if `isEventTimestamp="true"`) are treated as unicode strings and the value is inserted via the `PreparedStatement.setNString` method. If you configure your columns with `isUnicode="false"`, values are inserted via the `PreparedStatement.setString`, which should work. Example column configuration:

```
  <Appenders>
    <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="dbo.application_log">
      <DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/LoggingDataSource" />
      <Column name="eventDate" isEventTimestamp="true" />
      <Column name="level" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false" />
      <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" isUnicode="false" />
      <Column name="message" pattern="%message" isUnicode="false" />
      <Column name="exception" pattern="%ex{full}" isUnicode="false" />
    </JDBC>
  </Appenders>
```

Comment: even i suspected the same...i have tried with ojdbc6 11.2.0.2 and ojdbc14 driver version but no luck.

Comment: I thought it was a problem of the driver, but looking at the docs and the code I realized I was wrong. I modified my answer.

Comment: I had same problem, @RemkoPopma ur answer did solve the problem for me. Thanks.