# org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V

Tags: mysql, log4j2

Trying logging with log4j2 in a mysql database I've this error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, all columns (except if isEventTimestamp="true") are treated as unicode strings and the value is inserted via the PreparedStatement.setNString method. If you configure your columns with isUnicode="false", values are inserted via the PreparedStatement.setString, which should work.

See also [log4j2 JDBC Appender Issue:Failed to Insert Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242137/log4j2-jdbc-appender-issuefailed-to-insert-record)