# Log4j jdbc appender for DB2 in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, db2, log4j2

I'm trying to use *Log4j 2* to save the logs generated from a web application into a table in a *DB2 10.5* database. As a servlet container i'm using *Tomcat 8.*
My data source declaration, inside Tomcat's ***context.xml***:

```
  <Resource 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          name="jdbc/NCRDS" 
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
          driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
          url="jdbc:db2://192.168.1.58:50000/NCR" 
          username="admin"
          password="admin"
          initialSize="0"
          maxActive="80" 
          maxIdle = "30" 
          minIdle="20"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationQuery="VALUES 1" 
          validationInterval="30000" 
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
          logAbandoned="true" 
          abandonWhenPercentageFull="60"
          jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"/>
```

The appender declared insinde ***log4j2.xml***:

```
 <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="admin.logs">
<DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/NCRDS" />
<Column name="evendDate" isEventTimestamp="true" />
<Column name="Level" pattern="%level" />
<Column name="Logger" pattern="%logger" />
<Column name="Message" pattern="%msg" />
</JDBC>
```

The jdbc resource is also declared in my application's web.xml file. While i've managed to insert the logs on a *MySQL* database (changing of course the required information in my configuration files), i'm not able to achieve the same in DB2. The following stack trace part is what seems to be causing the problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:233)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.setNString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeInternal(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:167)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:105)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:430)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:409)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:367)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:738)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:708)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.debug(AbstractLogger.java:237)
    at com.ikubinfo.fileservice.FileSystemFileManager.<init>(FileSystemFileManager.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 24 more
```

I can't seem to find any information regarding this error and i really can explain to myself what's going wrong. I'd be very grateful for your help.
What i'm using: *Eclipse Luna, Tomcat 8, DB2 10.5, db2jcc.jar , jdk1.7, log4j required jars*.

Comment: Take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242137/log4j2-jdbc-appender-issuefailed-to-insert-record

Comment: Thanks a lot Federico. I've actually never tried setting the Unicode parameter just because i've read somewhere that it wasn't necessary. Well, guess i was wrong. If you post it as an answer i'll give you the credit ;) /

Comment: You're welcome. I think it is best to mark as duplicate question, the answer is the same as the link. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, as mustaccio correctly stated, was that the `setNString()` method was called which was trying to set var args, but instead, the log4j2 implementation could offer only a `setString()` method for a DB2 configuration . This call was caused by the defined column names. My first case:

```
<Column name="Date" isEventTimestamp="true" />
<Column name="Level" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false"/>
<Column name="Logger" pattern="%logger" isUnicode="false"/>
<Column name="Message" pattern="%msg" isUnicode="false"/>
```

You can see the names had both upper and lower case chars. Now i've got two solutions:

1. I could have added the HTML entity for the quotation mark, because DB2 needs quotation marks to read lower-case chars. So the final form would have been: `<Column name="&quot;Date&quot;"`
2. The one which i'm following, rename the table names to upper-cases and simply do the same on the column references in log4j2.xml: `<Column name="DATE"`

Answer (score 4):

This: `Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.setNString` basically says that the DB2 driver does not implement the method `setNString()`, which Log4j is trying to use `at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeInternal(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:110)`.

Now, what to do about it I can't tell. May be there is a parameter that can instruct Log4j to use `setString()` instead, or may be, Log4j being open source, you could edit the `JdbcDatabaseManager` class.

Comment: Or upgrade to a version of your JDBC driver that supports JDBC 4.0 which has been out for ... how long, now? 7 years? https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/10/whats-new-in-jdbc-40.html

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply @mustaccio. Actually that was the problem, and as Federico had posted as a comment, there is an easy way to use setString() instead of setNString. Just setting 'isUnicode="false"' for each output parameter was enough